# Frustration with fancyhdr

Tags: latex, tex

I have the following tex document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=3cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection}{}}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\setlength\marginparwidth{1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO,L]{Book template}
\fancyhead[RO,R]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[CO,C] {\thepage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Intro}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter with subsections}
\section{section foo}
\lipsum
\subsection{subsection bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

A sample can be viewed at http://www.mediafire.com/?0m5mnka32kj

On the top right:

- How to make it show the chapter title if there is no section, as on page 2?
- How to make it show the section title and nothing but the section title (no numbers, no subsections, subsubsections, etc) if there is an active section, as it's the case on page 4?

Thanks

Comment: I only started messing with headers a week ago, so I can't be much help.  Did you see the marks section in the fancyhdr documentation? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf

Comment: I suggest you read http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf expecially where the "mark" and connected "command" are explained. You need to do a little bit of work with chaptermark, sectionmark and subsectionmark and of course left, right mark and markboth; consider also you could find useful some other pkgs cited in the doc of the above link. Not a real answer, but I hope the reading can be enlightening

Comment: I have read that manual, and never managed to get the marks correctly on the logical page. Fancyhdr should do the work under the hood, why do I have to repeatedly fix stuff by trial and error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there!

The following two marks should do the trick:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
```

Be sure to move them to to a position **after** `\pagestyle{fancy}`. Also be sure to remove the custom `\subsectionmark`, unless you want to use some subsection information in the headers.

Comment: Thanks. Have a virtual beer from me. Cheers :-)